# cql query statement is not working when i using timestamp string

Tags: python, cassandra, cql, scylla

[image]
[image]

what is the problem in my code?

Comment: Please don't use images for code and error messages.  It's hard to read and impossible to copy/paste into the answer text.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that there are special characters in the variables causing an issue.  A prepared statement is a good way to insulate against that.  So instead of this:

```
session.execute("INSERT INTO test_table(id,time) VALUES ({},{});".format(uuid.uuid1(),timestamp))
```

Try using a prepared statement, like this:

```
strCQL = "INSERT INTO test_table(id,time) VALUES (?,?);"
pStatement = session.prepare(strCQL)
session.execute(pStatement,[uuid.uuid1(),timestamp])
```